# EntityFramework Attach and update. Need help

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to update indexorder in the below code. No error but values are not updating in the DB. tried different ways but no success.

```
readonly WMEntities _db = new WMEntities();


 var subMenu = new SubMenu { Id = id };
            subMenu.EntityKey = new EntityKey("WMEntities.SubMenus", "Id", id);
            _db.Attach(subMenu);
            subMenu.IndexOrder = index;
            _db.SaveChanges();
----------------------------------------------------------------
            SubMenu subMenu = new SubMenu();
            subMenu.Id = id;
            subMenu.IndexOrder = index;
            _db.AttachTo("WMEntities.SubMenus", subMenu);
            _db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Second example will not work because index order is set before attaching but the first one should work. Can you check in SQLProfiler that update is performed in the database?

Comment: Sorry my stupid mistake. I was updating online DB and checking my changes in local db. My first solution is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [AttachAsModified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423414%28VS.91%29.aspx)?